# How to make the theme look like on the screenshot?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My site: https://www.gameron.pl/

I need to make the theme like in the screenshot for the resolution 719px and below:

[image]

I mean posts list of course. I tried to achieve it with various codes, but each works only on one resolution and is not adjusting to other resolutions.

Here's what works:

```
@media (max-width:719px){

    /* Thumbnail Image */
    .main a .wp-post-image{
        width:50%;
    }
}
```

Now I just need to move and adjust post title properly. Does anyone have an idea how can I do it? I feel like I tried everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `.post-thumbnail` has `float:none`, and your `.post-content` has `float:left`.

I changed it in the console so both `float:left` and `width:50%` and it works fine:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT7MN.png

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 719px) {
    .post-list .post-thumbnail {
        float: left;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
    .post-list .post-content {
        float:left;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 719px) {
    .main .post-list .post-thumbnail,
    .main .post-list .post-content {
        float: left;
        width: 49%;
    }

    .main .post-thumbnail {
        margin-right: 0.5em;
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]